# Parsing txt file

Tags: java, parsing, loops

I have to write a program that will parse baseball player info and hits,out,walk,ect from a txt file. For example the txt file may look something like this:
Sam Slugger,h,h,o,s,w,w,h,w,o,o,o,h,s
Jill Jenks,o,o,s,h,h,o,o
Will Jones,o,o,w,h,o,o,o,o,w,o,o

I know how to parse the file and can get that code running perfect. The only problem I am having is that we should only be printing the name for each player and 3 or their plays. For example:
Sam Slugger hit,hit,out
Jill Jenks out, out, sacrifice fly
Will Jones out, out, walk

I am not sure how to limit this and every time I try to cut it off at 3 I always get the first person working fine but it breaks the loop and doesn't do anything for all the other players.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadBaseBall{

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    int count=0;
    String playerData;
    Scanner fileScan, urlScan;

    String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Crust\\Documents\\java\\TeamStats.txt";
    fileScan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    while(fileScan.hasNext()){

        playerData = fileScan.nextLine();
        fileScan.useDelimiter(",");

        //System.out.println("Name: " + playerData);

        urlScan = new Scanner(playerData);
        urlScan.useDelimiter(",");


        for(urlScan.hasNext(); count<4; count++)

            System.out.print(" " + urlScan.next() + ",");

        System.out.println();

        }
    }
}
```

This prints out:
 Sam Slugger, h, h, o,
but then the other players are voided out. I need help to get the other ones printing as well.

Comment: Do you have control of the file format?

Comment: Sadly no. The file is supposed to have the potential to be infinite.  There could be as many players as the file has in it.

Comment: You need to reset your `count` variable, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this one using FileReader
Assuming your file content format is like this

```
 Sam Slugger,h,h,o,s,w,w,h,w,o,o,o,h,s
 Jill Johns,h,h,o,s,w,w,h,w,o,o,o,h,s
```

with each player in the his/her own line then this can work for you

```
 BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] values_per_line = line.split(",");
            System.out.println("Name:" + values_per_line[0] + " "
                    + values_per_line[1] + " " + values_per_line[2] + " "
                    + values_per_line[3]);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

otherwise if they are lined all in like one line which would not make sense then modify this sample.

```
 Sam Slugger,h,h,o,s,w,w,h,w,o,o,o,h,s| John Slugger,h,h,o,s,w,w,h,w,o,o,o,h,s

 BufferedReader reader;
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.txt")));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // token identifier is a space
            String[] data = line.trim().split("|");
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                System.out.println("Name:" + data[0].split(",")[0] + " "
                        + data[1].split(",")[1] + " "
                        + data[2].split(",")[2] + " "
                        + data[3].split(",")[3]);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Problem**

Change `while(fileScan.hasNext()))` to `while(fileScan.hasNextLine())`. Not a breaking problem but when using scanner you usually put `sc.*` right after a `sc.has*`.

**Second Problem**

Remove the line `fileScan.useDelimiter(",")`. This line doesn't do anything in this case but replaces the default delimiter so the scanner no longer splits on whitespace. Which doesn't matter when using `Scanner.nextLine`, but can have some nasty side effects later on.

**Third Problem**

Change this line `for(urlScan.hasNext(); count<4; count++)` to `while(urlScan.hasNext())`. Honestly I'm surprised that line even compiled and if it did it only read the first 4 from the scanner.

If you want to limit the amount processed for each line you can replace it with

`for( int count = 0; count < limit && urlScan.hasNext( ); count++ )`

This will limit the amount read to `limit` while still handling lines that have less data than the limit.

Make sure that each of your data sets is separated by a line otherwise the output might not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your `count` car in the while loop:

```
 while(fileScan.hasNext()){
        count = 0;
        ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple scanners on this - assuming the format you posted in your question you can use regular expressions to do this.

This demonstrates a regular expression to match a player and to use as a delimiter for the scanner. I fed the scanner in my example a string, but the technique is the same regardless of source.

```
int count = 0;
Pattern playerPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s\\w+(?:,\\w){1,3}");
Scanner fileScan = new Scanner("Sam Slugger,h,h,o,s,w,w,h,w,o,o,o,h,s Jill Jenks,o,o,s,h,h,o,o Will Jones,o,o,w,h,o,o,o,o,w,o,o");
fileScan.useDelimiter("(?<=,\\w)\\s");

while (fileScan.hasNext()){
    String player = fileScan.next();
    Matcher m = playerPattern.matcher(player);
    if (m.find()) {
        player = m.group(0);
    } else {
        throw new InputMismatchException("Players data not in expected format on string: " + player);
    }
    System.out.println(player);
    count++;
}
System.out.printf("%d players found.", count);
```

Output:

```
Sam Slugger,h,h,o
Jill Jenks,o,o,s
Will Jones,o,o,w
```

The call to `Scanner.delimiter()` sets the delimiter to use for retrieving tokens. The regex `(?<=,\\w)\\s`:

```
(?<                             // positive lookbehind
    ,\w                         // literal comma, word character
)
\s                              // whitespace character
```

Which delimits the players by the space between their entries without matching anything but that space, and fails to match the space between the names.

The regular expression used to extract up to 3 plays per player is `\\w+\\s\\w+(?:,\\w){1,3}`:

```
\w+                             // matches one to unlimited word characters
(?:                             // begin non-capturing group
    ,\w                         // literal comma, word character
){1,3}                          // match non-capturing group 1 - 3 times
```

Comment: Thanks guys, these answers really helped a ton and now I got it working.

Comment: @cweidner55 if this answer solved your problem, click the green check.